# Android: Scrollable tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I'm currently working on my first android application. I am using a tabbed layout for my application. I followed the tutorial for this on the dev guide and ran into a problem. The tutorial only used three tabs, but I have a need for more. As such, the tabs resize and bunch up. I was hoping someone could tell me how I can make them scroll, like in dolphin browser when using multiple tabs. Thanks!

~aaron

Answer (score 12):

Using what Yoel said, just add:
    `android:fillViewport="true` and
    `android:scrollbars="none"`

to HorizontalScrollView like this:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView 
       android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:fillViewport="true"
       android:scrollbars="none" >

       <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to wrap the TabWidget with HotizontalScrollView instead. this way you can still use the tabs as they are.

```
    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

It is important to note that if you are using less tabs, this will cause the tab's not to fill the whole width of the screen. I am currently looking for a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you probably dont want to use tabs. Rather, you can put all of your "tabs" in to a horizontal linear layout at the top of the screen wrapped in a ScrollView like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        ...buttons go here...

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I think that this will give you the result you are looking for, but let me know

Comment: edited to use HorizontalScrollView instead of ScrollView (which scrolls vertical only)

Comment: Thanks. I will attempt to implement it this way and let you know.